# Forward button functionality

Tags: android

Can i give functionality of a forward button in my android app. In case of web app, the URLS and session id is stored in the stack so we can provide this functionality. But can we provide a similar kind of functionality in our mobile app using activities.If yes then how and what would be the implications of the same.

if i don't kill my activities, then wouldn't it create memory issues??

Thanks..

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? Its hard to follow whats going on.

Comment: I think he wants to move forward and backward through activities as if they were webpages.

Comment: what is MyAccessableStorageFacility class? And if i don't kill my activities, then wouldn't it create memory issues??

Comment: I think Greg's answer is flawed unlike my `brief explanation`.  That class is just something Greg made up ie a pseudo class that handles storing the activity so you know which to go back and forth to.  I believe his answer will just keep creating new activities.

Comment: MyAccessableStorageFacility could be a singleton that stores the intent or some other mechanism that you make. Also no it's not going to leak activities. The super back button functionality is to finish the activity. So no leak :) Not killing activities does not create memory issues either. Leaking a context reference does.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I think it would be pretty simple.

So if you are working with Android 2.0 There is a function,

there is a function in Activity called, onBackPressed(). If you have all your activities override this and do something like:

```
public void onBackPressed() { 
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 MyAccessableStorageFacility.storeForwardIntent(intent);
 super.onBackPressed();
}


public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 menu.add("Forward").setIntent(MyAccessableStorageFacility.getLastIntent());
 super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

If you don't have Android 2.0, just override the onKeyPressed method instead of the onBackPressed and look for the keycode of the back button and write the same code to save the last intent.

Comment: why did you post what i have posted.  btw `onBackPressed` is from API 5 up i.e. 2.0.

Comment: sorry was going off memory. Thanks 1.5 just truncated the 5 in my head, anyways, I didn't realize you with your almighty wisdom had replied already. I was editing my response while you had submitted I guess. Next time I shall refresh over and over until such time I find that your answer may or may not have graced us with it's brief explanation :) Or we could just chill and not take life so seriously :)

Comment: i guess not since you just -1'd me on a post from soooooooooooo long ago.  lmao.  btw stackoverflow sticks a bar on the top of the page telling you someone else is posting an answer...

Comment: btw I marked your answer back up but it went to +1 and then marking down would go -1, so I left it at +1.  However, have you tested to check that your code does not start a new activity?

Comment: that's why I call super. It's safe to start a new activity :) since the default impl of onBackPressed() will call finish(). Without much Context I don't know of a safer approach. FWIW, I think both our answers are acceptable. I just like providing code because a lot of times it's clearer than words for peeps like us :)

Comment: i see where your'e coming from and if he does not want to keep the activities state and reload from fresh then your method is ok. as you say there isn't much context.  i try not to paste code in the first instance as they just try and c&p without learning.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you would need to set the `launchMode` of each activity to `SingleTop`.  Second, you would need to stop the back button from calling `onDestroy` and get it to do `startActivity` with an `Intent` set to the class of the `Activity` below.